# Where do I add and remove event listeners in the Ember controller life cycle?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, callback, geolocation, listener

If I want to listen for certain events or callbacks *only on a certain route,* and stop listening when not on that route. Where would I write that code?

There are a lot of hooks and events in an Ember component life cycle, but I cannot find any documentation on where to listen and unlisten for route-specific events or callbacks.

An example would be **Listening to GPS coordinates:**

```
// Listen
this.set('watch', navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(watchFn))

// Unlisten
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.get('watch'))
```

(Note that I want to listen on the route/controller, not on a component.)

First thought is to set the watch at `__init()`, but the controller is a singleton so this will fire only once.

Second thought is to set actions for [`activate()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Route/events/activate?anchor=activate) and [`deactivate()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Route/events/deactivate?anchor=deactivate) in the route. <strike>They don't seem to fire (using `console.log` test statements) so I am probably using them wrong.</strike> **Update:** I had accidentally placed them inside `actions`. They work as hooks. <strike>However, now I cannot fire actions inside the controller because `this.controller` does not exist, as opposed to `didTransition()`.</strike> **Update:** To access the controller, we need to do `this.controllerFor('route')`†¹.

Next candidate is [`setupController()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Route/methods/setupController?anchor=setupController) and [`resetController()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Route/methods/resetController?anchor=resetController). The `resetController()` seems to work reliably indeed and fires every time I leave the route. But `setupController()` also seems to fire only once. Which might make sense, since the controller is a singleton. To access the controller, we can simply use the first argument (`controller`)†².

Then I thought I could use [`willTransition()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Route/events/willTransition?anchor=willTransition) or [`didTransition()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Route/events/didTransition?anchor=didTransition) in stead of `setupController()`. They work as expected for starting the listeners *when navigating to a different route first.* To access the controller, we can do `this.controller`†³.

But when I navigate away to a route that redirects back to this route, although both hooks executed, it *seems like* `resetController()` is fired after `didTransition()`. I'm not sure if that's what happens, but the effect is the same: The listeners stop listening, but they don't start listening. If I navigate away to an unrelated route and back again, the listeners will be activated again.

I'm stuck in the maze of possibilities.

1. **How can/should I achieve this?** (I assume this is a normal approach. But if not: I'm out of time. Willing to do ugly hacks at this point.)
2. Is there a best practice and/or *"Ember way"* to achieve this type of `on(x)` `off(x)` behavior?
3. †¹²³ - What is the rhetoric behind these different controller accessibility methods?

Comment: What's not working with activate/deactivate? Can you provide a twiddle to demonstrate when it's not firering?

Comment: activate and deactivate should fire correctly, but make sure you are actually entering and leaving the route you put them on (not just transitioning between subroutes).

Comment: @Lux @Gaurav **Update:** `activate`/`deactivate` do work. I had accidentally placed them inside `actions`. However I cannot reference `this.controller`, which I can do in `didTransition` and `resetController` so the latter two seem better candidates. However, there are too many options, so I am desparately looking for an answer to sub-question 2.

Comment: the *ember way* is `activate`/`deactivate`. Probably in combination with a `service`. The interesting question is what you want to do with the events. Oh, and you *can* access the controller if you really need to. `controllerFo` should do the trick.

Comment: @Lux thank you for `controllerFor`. It helps. Although I don't understand the rhetoric behind the 3 (!) different types of accessing the controller required in a single route file. `controllerFor` is the most distant out of the 3, as if they discourage using it this way. Hence, it doesn't _feel_ like this is the _Ember way_. As to your question, the example provided in the question should be a good indicator. If one out of 50 routes watches GPS coordinates, you don't want the other 49 routes to watch GPS coordinates, as it would drain your battery.

Comment: But what do you do with the GPS coordinates? Probably I would do it in a service and star/stop it from a component where I *show* or *use* the data.

Comment: @Lux where _exactly_ would you fire the start/stop actions on the service in your component code?

Comment: `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement`. Usually you need the GPS info as long you need to show them, so it makes sense to bind them to the view.